# epoll fd and epoll_wait on pmqs

Tags: epoll

I am using epoll fd to wait on posix message queues.
My question: What happens to epoll_wait, if there are already messages sent in message queues.(There are already some messages sent to message queues before I call epoll_wait). Will it return with those mq fds ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. `epoll_wait(2)` will return immediately if there is already available I/O (according to the events you subscribe) when you call it.